# Puppeteer Cluster - Idle browser workers inactivity

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I want to ask, Using puppeteer-cluster library with CONCURRENCY_BROWSER model, are all the browsers in the pool kept open always till my application is running?

Or are they closed and removed from the pool once inactive and idle for a specific period of time?

Also, if they are removed from the pool after a specific period, is there any way we can explicitly define that duration?

Asking, as keeping browsers open always takes a lot of resources.